# why float is not working?

Tags: c, floating-point, floating-point-conversion

in my code, the output is 2.000000 whereas it's supposed to be 2.11111

```
#include<stdio.h>main(){
int i,j;
float r;
i = 19;
j = 9;
r = i / j;
printf(" %f ",r);}
```

why it's not working?

Comment: **r = i / j; ==> r=(float)i/j;'**

Answer (score 8):

Because `i / j` is integer division (both operands are integers). It doesn't make any difference that you store the result in a `float`.

You would get the desired result if one of `i` and `j` were a float, e.g.:

```
r = ((float)i) / j;
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
r = i / j;
```

with

```
r = i / (float) j;
```

`i` and `j` are integers and `i / j` is a integer division.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the division is done in integers before being assigned to a `float`. Change the type of `i` and `j` to `float` to get it fixed:

```
main(){
    float i,j,r;
    i = 19;
    j = 9;
    r = i / j;
    printf(" %f ",r);
}
```

Alternatively, you can cast `i` to `float` in the division, like this:

```
r = ((float)i) / j;
```

Answer (score 0):

Diving two integers wilds a integer (in your case `2` which is later converted to a float):

Just convert `i` or `j` to float (or declare them as floats to begin with):

```
r = ((float) i) / j;
```

---

[Working example](http://ideone.com/gxjagx)

Answer (score 0):

Here, int was converted to float by default after the RHS (integer division, the result of which is by default the quotient = an integer) was evaluated.That's why you get 2.000000.
Typecast any number in RHS to get the result you seek.

See you need to understand type conversions in c and then casting.Check them in any good source.
Generally, automatic conversions are those which can convert a narrower operand into a wider one without loss of information. For example, converting an integer to floating point in examples like float + integer (on 64-bit machine).[from wiki].

e.g float x =7.8 ; int k=9; int j = k + x = 16 .

Here, first k is coverted to float, then added and then finally the result is truncated to an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `i / j` is integer division (both operands are integers),so their division results in an integer number (with the fractional part discareded) which is again assigned to a float type of variable `r` so the compiler typecasts(i.e.implicit typecasting) the integer result to `float` again to show 2.000000

You would get the desired result if one of i and j were a float, e.g.:

`r = ((float)i) / j;` //explicit typecasting